# Finding Cumulative Sum In R Using Conditions

Tags: r, sum

I need to create a new variable with the sum of the past three years' amounts for each ID.

If there are not three years' worth of data, there should be an 'NA'.

As an example:

```
ID YEAR   AMOUNT
1 2010      5
1 2011      2
1 2012      4
1 2013      1
1 2014      3
2 2013      4
2 2014      6
2 2015      9
3 2012      4
3 2013      7
3 2014      2
3 2015      3
```

Here's what the result should be:

```
ID YEAR AMOUNT THREE_YR
1 2010      5       NA
1 2011      2       NA
1 2012      4       11
1 2013      1        7
1 2014      3        8
2 2013      4       NA
2 2014      6       NA
2 2015      9       19
3 2012      4       NA
3 2013      7       NA
3 2014      2       13
3 2015      3       12
```

How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: See `zoo::rollsum`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `zoo`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "ID YEAR   AMOUNT
1 2010      5
                 1 2011      2
                 1 2012      4
                 1 2013      1
                 1 2014      3
                 2 2013      4
                 2 2014      6
                 2 2015      9
                 3 2012      4
                 3 2013      7
                 3 2014      2
                 3 2015      3",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(THREE_YR = rollsum(AMOUNT, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

#### Update: ID groups with less than 3 records.

The OP asked what to do if there are IDs with only one or two rows. Honestly, I did not find a good way to solve this. The only thing I can think of is dividing the original data frame to two groups, apply the `rollsum` to the group with all records larger than or equal to three. After that, combine all groups.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "ID YEAR   AMOUNT
                 1 2010      5
                 1 2011      2
                 1 2012      4
                 1 2013      1
                 1 2014      3
                 2 2013      4
                 3 2012      4
                 3 2013      7
                 3 2014      2
                 3 2015      3",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  mutate(THREE_YR = rollsum(AMOUNT, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right")) %>%
  bind_rows(dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() < 3)) %>%
  arrange(ID, YEAR)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: k <= n is not TRUE." Some of the IDs only have one row (not 3 or more)... Any way to correct this?

Comment: Are you talking about the example dataset or your real dataset? It is likely that for some ID groups you only got one or two records. `rollsum` will fail for those IDs.

Comment: Correct. In my real dataset there are some ID groups with only one or two records. Any idea what would work in such a case?

Comment: Try to change the `mutate` call to this: `mutate(THREE_YR = ifelse(n() >= 3, rollsum(AMOUNT, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "right"), NA))`

Comment: This mutate yields NA straight down the THREE_YR column... [In the dataset I sent, imagine there was only one row for ID 2.] Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

With the `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
setorder(dt,YEAR)
dt[,.(YEAR,AMOUNT,THREE_YR=AMOUNT+shift(AMOUNT,1)+shift(AMOUNT,2)),by=.(ID)]
#ID YEAR AMOUNT THREE_YR
# 1:  1 2010      5       NA
# 2:  1 2011      2       NA
# 3:  1 2012      4       11
# 4:  1 2013      1        7
# 5:  1 2014      3        8
# 6:  3 2012      4       NA
# 7:  3 2013      7       NA
# 8:  3 2014      2       13
# 9:  3 2015      3       12
#10:  2 2013      4       NA
#11:  2 2014      6       NA
#12:  2 2015      9       19
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zoo::rollapplyr()` and `aggregate()`
This will return `NA` if there are less than three members in a group.

```
x <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L), YEAR = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2013L, 2014L, 
  2015L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L), AMOUNT = c(5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
  3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID", "YEAR", "AMOUNT"
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

library(zoo)

rsum <- aggregate(AMOUNT ~ ID, data=x, 
  FUN=function(x) rollapplyr(x, 3, fill=NA, partial=TRUE,
  FUN=function(y) if (length(y) >= 3) sum(y) else NA))

x$rsum <- do.call(c, rsum$AMOUNT)
x
#    ID YEAR AMOUNT rsum
# 1   1 2010      5   NA
# 2   1 2011      2   NA
# 3   1 2012      4   11
# 4   1 2013      1    7
# 5   1 2014      3    8
# 6   2 2013      4   NA
# 7   2 2014      6   NA
# 8   2 2015      9   19
# 9   3 2012      4   NA
# 10  3 2013      7   NA
# 11  3 2014      2   13
# 12  3 2015      3   12

# remove one of the 2s
x <- x[-6, ]

rsum <- aggregate(AMOUNT ~ ID, data=x, 
  FUN=function(x) rollapplyr(x, 3, fill=NA, partial=TRUE,
  FUN=function(y) if (length(y) >= 3) sum(y) else NA))


x$rsum <- do.call(c, rsum$AMOUNT)
x
#    ID YEAR AMOUNT rsum
# 1   1 2010      5   NA
# 2   1 2011      2   NA
# 3   1 2012      4   11
# 4   1 2013      1    7
# 5   1 2014      3    8
# 7   2 2014      6   NA
# 8   2 2015      9   NA
# 9   3 2012      4   NA
# 10  3 2013      7   NA
# 11  3 2014      2   13
# 12  3 2015      3   12
```